# checking null condition with linq to entites using multiple joins

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have query like this ...below... I want to check the null condition ...

if lastname(entered name) is empty dont check this condition ...

```
report.member_Lastname.StartsWith(lastname)
```

if cardnum is empty dont check this condition

```
&& report.member_CardNum == cardnum
```

I am using linq to entities and i am not using linq to sql

```
var memberreport = from report in eclipse.members
                   join memtomship in eclipse.membertomships on report.member_Id equals memtomship.member_Id
                   join mshoption in eclipse.mshipoptions on memtomship.mshipOption_Id equals mshoption.mshipOption_Id
                   join membershiptypes in eclipse.mshiptypes on mshoption.mshipType_Id equals membershiptypes.mshipType_Id
                   join membershipstatustypes in eclipse.mshipstatustypes on memtomship.mshipStatusType_Id equals membershipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id                             
                   where report.member_Lastname.StartsWith(lastname)
                      && report.member_CardNum == cardnum 
                      && report.member_Postcode.StartsWith(postcode)
                      && report.member_Reference.StartsWith(refernce)
                      && report.member_Gender.StartsWith(gender)
                      && membershiptypes.mshipType_Name.StartsWith(membershiptype)
                      && membershipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name.StartsWith(membershipstatustypesa)
                      && string.Compare(report.member_Dob,maxage) >= 0
                      && string.Compare(report.member_Dob, minage)< 0
                   select new
                   {
                       report.member_Id,
                       report.member_Lastname,
                       report.member_Firstname,
                       report.member_Postcode,
                       report.member_Reference,
                       report.member_CardNum,
                       report.member_IsBiometric,
                       report.member_Dob,
                       membershiptypes.mshipType_Name,
                       membershipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name,
                       memtomship.memberToMship_EndDate
                   };
```

would you guys pls suggest any idea and any code sample snippet for this..

Many thanks in advance ....

Modify :

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname))
    query = query.Where(r => r.member_Lastname == lastname);
```

i want something like above, i know this query using linq to sql but i am using linq to entities

Comment: && (report.member_CardNum == cardnum || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cardnum))

Comment: @zespri does not working with your condition.

Comment: "does not work" tells me nothing. please be more specific, I can't read your mind.

Comment: @zespri i have tried the condition that you have specified above but it does not work for me ..r u clear..

Comment: No.I'm referring to the fact that "does not work" is not a very good description of what has happened. It does not provide as much information as it could have. I used this pattern with EF many times and I know that it works. I understand that it does not for you. You need to be more specific to get further help.

Answer (score 0):

&& works stops on first false so you can write

```
...                          
where  
   (report.member_Lastname != null && report.member_Lastname.StartsWith(lastname))
&& ...
```

same with || and first true, so if you want Lastname to be null or startwith lastname you can use

```
...                          
where  
   (report.member_Lastname == null || report.member_Lastname.StartsWith(lastname))
&& ...
```

same with cardnum and wherever you want it. To get the values you can use

```
report.member_Lastname ?? "yourNullDefault"
```

assuming member_Lastname is a string

Comment: is there any way to check entered name is correct or not) not checking table field value in database....

Comment: what is the entered name here and it depends if null is correct or not - see both examples above (first for it is not correct, second for it is correct)

Comment: see my modified code i want something like the above not checking database  table field value is null or not , i want to check that whether user is entering name or not ..something like that ..